# Display Values on Bars of a Bar chart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-charts

I want to display values on the top of the bars in asp.net chart.
Also I want to hide the x axis while displaying it. 
For mock up please see the image below. Thanks.

[image: Bar Chart with values on Bar in asp.net]

I tried following but doesn't work.

```
var c = HorizontalChart;
        //c.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("HChartArea"));
        //c.ChartAreas[0].BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.None;
        c.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        c.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        c.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels="Code here for Lable values" <-------------
        c.Width = 300;
        c.Height = 300;
        Series myHorizontalSeries = new Series();
        myHorizontalSeries.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        myHorizontalSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        myHorizontalSeries.Points.DataBindXY(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        c.Series.Add(myHorizontalSeries);
```

Comment: Did you try setting `IsValueShownAsLabel` to true for the series ?

Comment: Ok that worked.Thanks a lot for clue.
But How to remove the x axis to hide its visibility

Comment: Added as answer check if it works for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try setting the Axis Enabled property to false

```
c.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```

To show the values you set the `IsValueShownAsLabel` property of the series to `true`

Comment: c.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
this was my requirement thnx :)

Answer (score 7):

You may try :

I want to display values on the top of the bars in asp.net chart.

```
myHorizontalSeries.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

Also I want to hide the x axis while displaying it.

```
c.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```

Answer (score 4):

another example you can show values like labels

```
c.Series[myHorizontalSeries].Label = "#VALY";
```

Hope I've helped.